# Whats the difference between the print statement in boolean indexing?

Tags: python, pandas

What's the difference between this two `print()` statement in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(data=[90, 65, 43, 99],
               index=['path', 'pulkit', 'gaurav', 'piyush'])

print(s1 >= 80)
print(s1[s1 >= 80])
```

The output for the first

```
>>> print(s1 >= 80)
path       True
pulkit    False
gaurav    False
piyush     True
dtype: bool
```

Output for the second

```
>>> print(s1[s1 >= 80])
path      90
piyush    99
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s1 >= 80` is a `comparison statement` where you compare each element of s1 against the static value `80`. The output is the result of this comparison for each element in `s1`.

Whereas `s1[s1 >= 80]` is a `boolean indexing`, where the inner `s1 >= 80` similar to the above statement, returns `true` or `false` based on the comparison result and then this is used by `s1[...]` to filter the values from `s1` where the result of the comparison was `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In this line : `s1 >= 80` you check values in s1 >= 80 and you get `True` or `False` for cheking.

But in this line `s1[s1 >= 80]` you get value in `s1` that index is `True` you can write this line like this `s1[[True, False, False, True]]`.